Using "Constructor Injection" the right way - How to handle Dependencies in calling classes?
I wonder if I am making a mistake in my thinking when using “Constructor Injection”.
Given two rules, which have completely different tasks and dependencies to use.
To make them unit-testable I do inject those dependencies through the constructor.
class RuleA implements MyInterface {

 private DependencyA_1 dependencyA1;
 private DependencyA_2 dependencyA2;

 public RuleA(DependencyA_1 dependencyA1, DependencyA_2 dependencyA2) {
    this.dependencyA1 = dependencyA1;
    this.dependencyA2 = dependencyA2;
}

 public Result execute() {
....
}

class RuleB implements MyInterface {

 private DependencyB_1 dependencyB1;
 private DependencyB_2 dependencyB2;

 public RuleB(DependencyB_1 dependencyB1, DependencyB_2 dependencyB2) {
    this.dependencyB1 = dependencyB1;
    this.dependencyB2 = dependencyB2;
}

 public Result execute() {
....
}

Only given a String (e.g. from a DB-result) to create the right rule, I create a Factory for the instantiation.
But if I do that, my factory needs to know every dependency of all my rules which (in my opinion) is big coupling issue and if i wanted to unit-test my factory, I need to mock all those dependencies, which my factory shouldn't be aware of.
So for production code I would add non-argument constructors to RuleA and RuleB in which the "real" objects get instantiated like:
public RuleA(DependencyA_1 dependencyA1, DependencyA_2 dependencyA2) {
    this.dependencyA1 = dependencyA1;
    this.dependencyA2 = dependencyA2;
}

public RuleA() {
    this(new MyProductiveDependencyA1(), new MyProductiveDependencyA2());
}

....

class Factory {

  public MyInterface createClass(String type) {
     if ("A".equals(type)) {
         return new RuleA();
     }

     if ("B".equals(type)) {
         return new RuleB();
     }

}

But now my factory or any other class which is using it is not unit-testable because of using the production constructors of RuleA and RuleB which might require a running DB or whatever external modules.
So my questions are:

Is it a good pattern to use one constructor for unit-testing and another one for "normal/production" use (if there is no logic in it of course)?
If I use the unit-testing constructor in calling classes, they need to know all the dependencies of the called class and when thinking of deeper hierarchies this could get very messy. If I use the non-arg constructor, the calling class is not unit-testable. What do I do? Do I need to accept, that those classes can only be tested in integration tests or this a smell of a bad software design?

I know that there are a couple of Dependency Injection Frameworks using annotations so I can mock needed dependencies without passing them through the constructors, but I would like to avoid them if possible.

You can parameterize the factory with associations that will define the dependency of the class, an instance of which the factory needs to create, on the type that is passed to this factory as text.
"A" -> RuleA.class
"B" -> RuleB.class

For example, as follows
class Factory<T> {

    private record Description<T>(Class<? extends T> target, Class<?>[] parameters) {
    }
    private final Map<Class<?>, Object> context = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Description<T>> mapping = new HashMap<>();

    public T create(String type) throws Exception {
        Description<T> description = mapping.get(type);
        Constructor<? extends T> constructor = description.target.getConstructor(description.parameters);
        return constructor.newInstance(Arrays.stream(description.parameters).map(context::get).toArray());
    }

    public <K, V extends K> void addBean(Class<K> clazz, V bean) {
        context.put(clazz, bean);
    }

    public void addMapping(String type, Class<? extends T> clazz, Class<?>... parameters) {
        mapping.put(type, new Description<>(clazz, parameters));
    }
}

Now the factory does not depend on specific types and you can test its operation on arbitrary classes.
In a production environment, you can create a factory:
Factory<MyInterface> factory = new Factory<>();

And then configure it to produce instances of RuleA and RuleB:
factory.addMapping("A", RuleA.class, DependencyA_1.class, DependencyA_2.class);
factory.addMapping("B", RuleB.class, DependencyB_1.class, DependencyB_2.class);
factory.addBean(DependencyA_1.class, new DependencyA_1());
factory.addBean(DependencyA_2.class, new DependencyA_2());
factory.addBean(DependencyB_1.class, new DependencyB_1());
factory.addBean(DependencyB_2.class, new DependencyB_2());

As a result, calling the factory.create("A") method will create an instance of the RuleA class, and calling the factory.create("B") method will create an instance of the RuleB class.

Q. Is it a good pattern to use one constructor for unit-testing and another one for "normal/production" use (if there is no logic in it of course)?
A. No it is not at all a good practice. In fact using different constructors for testing and production often indicates a design issue.
One of the easiest solution is wrapping the dependency at higher level and use new class in Factory.
Instead of directly creating RuleA and RuleB in the factory, try to use a dependency injector within the factory so that factory does not know about the dependencies:
class Factory {
    public MyInterface createClass(String type) {
        if ("A".equals(type)) {
            return Injector.createRuleA();
        }
        if ("B".equals(type)) {
            return Injector.createRuleB();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: " + type);
    }
}

class Injector {
    public static RuleA createRuleA() {
        return new RuleA(new DependencyA_1(), new DependencyA_2());
    }

    public static RuleB createRuleB() {
        return new RuleB(new DependencyB_1(), new DependencyB_2());
    }
}

Mock the interface dependencies during unit testing.
Edit -- Added unit test without using mocking or DI
public class FactoryTest {

    @Test
    void testCreateClassA() {
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        MyInterface result = factory.createClass("A");
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertTrue(result instanceof RuleA);
    }

    @Test
    void testCreateClassB() {
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        MyInterface result = factory.createClass("B");
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertTrue(result instanceof RuleB);
    }

    @Test
    void testCreateClassUnknownType() {
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            factory.createClass("C");
        });
    }
}



thanks for the solution. may you point out how to unit test the factory now? without using a DI-framework or mockito? and I guess the injector isn't something that needs to be tested?

I have updated and added a sample unit test in the answer. Let me know if this helps.

We must add tests for injector too. In an ideal TDD  we first write tests then we update the body of the CUT(class under test) as per the desired requirement in test.
